# Odd RubyMine indenting when enter is pressed

Tags: rubymine

When I press <kbd>Enter</kbd> this happens:

```
 def spend_cash
    self.totals[order.type] = if order.cash > 0
                              // cursor is here                           
      order.cash / order.price
    end
  end
```

How do I fix something like this?
I want it inline with `order.cash`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This area might be the one to experiment with:

`Preferences | Editor | Code Style | Ruby`

... then try the settings on the `Tabs and indents` tab to see which works best for you.

It's probably the checkbox `Use indents relative to expression start`

Comment: This has been annoying me for months! - Thanks :D